# Combine rows adding specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to the following:

```
employee_id | totalWorkHours | projectID
     1             20              123
     1             20              321

     2             15              222
     2             25              333

     3             10              434
     3             12              343
```

Is it possible to combine rows based on employee_id, but add totalWorkHours into an actual total for an employee and present in a result set without modifying the table?

So the results would be something like:

```
employee_id | actualTotalWorkHours
     1                 40
     2                 40              
     3                 22
```

Or is this something better done with the raw result set?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select employee_id, Sum(totalWorkHours) As actualWorkHours
From   YourTableName
Group By employee_id
Order By employee_id
```